# Pandas turn True columns into column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table of boolean values:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': [True, False, False, True], 
                   'val2': [False, True, False, True], 
                   'val3': [True, True, False, True], 
                   'val4': [True, False, True, False], 
                   'val5': [True, True, False, False],
                   'val6': [False, False, True, True]},
                   index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
```

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True | True | True | False |
| 2 | False | True | True | False | True | False |
| 3 | False | False | False | True | False | True |
| 4 | True | True | True | False | False | True |

I want to create a new dataframe with the same indices, but each row has the first three True column names from the previous column.

| index | TrueVal1 | TrueVal2 | TrueVal3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | val3 | val4 |
| 2 | val2 | val3 | val5 |
| 3 | val4 | val6 | NaN |
| 4 | val1 | val2 | val3 |

If a row has fewer than three True values, the new dataframe will have Null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `dot` , then `split`

```
#df = df.set_index('index')
out = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1].str.split(',',expand=True).iloc[:,:3]
out
Out[258]: 
          0     1     2
index                  
1      val1  val3  val4
2      val2  val3  val5
3      val4  val6  None
4      val1  val2  val3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `numpy` + `argsort` to slice the columns by the position of the `True` values.

Then use `where` to `NaN` rows that were `False` incase there were too few `True` values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Get the first `N` True columns.
N = 3

arr = df.to_numpy()
data = df.columns.to_numpy()[(~arr).argsort(axis=1, kind='stable')[:, :N]]
mask = np.ones_like(data).cumsum(1) <= arr.sum(1)[:, None]

res = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'TrueVal{i+1}' for i in range(N)],
                   index=df.index).where(mask)
```

---

```
print(res)

      TrueVal1 TrueVal2 TrueVal3
index                           
1         val1     val3     val4
2         val2     val3     val5
3         val4     val6      NaN
4         val1     val2     val3
```